# tried to choose a random value from array (filled with ids from db) and it throws Index was outside the bounds of the array.' sometimes, why?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ado.net

basically when in another page someone chooses a category it redirects him to this page and adds "?category=(category he choose)" to the url, then it checks in this page what's his category and pulls the ids from db where the category is equal to what it chose, then it chooses a random id.

```
            Uri uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
            string querystring = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("category");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            List<int> idList = new List<int>();  
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data source");
            // I deleted the Data source but it's in the code
            try
            {

                cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT Id FROM Facts WHERE category='{querystring}'", con);
                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                int i = 0;
                while ((bool)reader.Read())
                {
                    idList.Add((int)reader.GetValue(0));
                    i++;
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int[] idArray = idList.ToArray();
            int randIndex = rnd.Next(idArray.Length);
            int random = idArray[randIndex];
            string SQL = $"SELECT facts FROM Facts WHERE id='{random}';";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
            con.Open();
            object scalar = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            con.Close();
```

this is the code, sometimes it works and sometimes it throws 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

really need an hand here, been working on it for a long time and i have no idea.

Comment: Many problems in your code.  But to start please add to the catch block some information about what is the value of _iqs_ and the value of the querystring when you get the exception

Comment: And if you are able to reproduce the exception then the best tool to solve the problem is your debugger.

Comment: @Steve iqs is the part of the url, it just gets the index of the query string parameter in the url, for example: example.com/test?foo=bar iqs is the index of foo=bar

_edit: it points to line 74 (`int random = idArray[randIndex];`), but i think that it's in the query string because that's the only place where it can throw the specific error, also, it only happens randomly after a couple of times_

Comment: Well, also the logic of the Substring extraction doesn't seem correct. The code checks if iqs is less than _currurl.Length-1;_ but then the code adds 10 to iqs for extracting the substring. Of course this could be wrong badly. At least you should check for  _currurl.Length - 11_

Comment: Changed it to -             `Uri uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
            string querystring = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("category");
`
But still getting the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using some of the ideas and answers brought here I managed to fix it, first of all I removed unused and unnecessary code (thanks to some advices) and debugged the code using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine();` then I took the entire code that gets the IDs and made a method with it -

```cs
List<int> GetData(string querystring)
        {
            // This method receives the URL query parameter of the category and outputs a list of all the fact ids in the category .
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            List<int> idList = new List<int>();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\RotemCohen\source\repos\firstsite\firstsite\App_Data\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT Id FROM Facts WHERE category='{querystring}'", con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                int i = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    idList.Add((int)reader.GetValue(0));
                    i++;
                }
                reader.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return idList;
        }
```

This part gets the facts id's and chooses a random one, then outputs it to HTML:

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\RotemCohen\source\repos\firstsite\firstsite\App_Data\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
Uri uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
string category = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("category");
List<int> listID = GetData(category);
Random rnd = new Random();
int random = rnd.Next(0, listID.Count);
List<int> listID = GetData(category);
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int random = rnd.Next(0, listID.Count);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(listID.Count);
            object randomFact;
            if(listID.Count != 0)
            {
                int randomFactID = listID[random];
                string SQLQuery = $"SELECT facts FROM Facts WHERE id='{randomFactID}';";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery, con);
                con.Open();
                randomFact = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                randomFact = "Error, Please try again";
            }
```

**NOTE: This is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks, don't use it without parameterizing the `SQLQuery` variable first! See [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Parameterized-Queries-ADO.Net.aspx) to learn about it.**

Answer (score 0):

It may be necessary to manage the case where there is no result :

```
...
if (idList.Count > 0)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int[] idArray = idList.ToArray();
    int randIndex = rnd.Next(idArray.Length);
    int random = idArray[randIndex];
    ...
```

Comment: first of all Thank you, it works
but when it's generates a number that isn't greater than one (or zero) it doesn't pull the required row from the db which is a problem...

Comment: If I understand correctly, the indexes 0 and 1 of the Array cause the error.
Could this be due to the source data ? (SELECT Id FROM Facts)

Comment: well maybe, but if it was than it wouldn't work at all, but since it works sometimes that's not likely...
for example the category nature has 3 facts in it (id 10-12), and most of the times it works, but when it generates a fact correctly, but than sometimes it just throws index out of bounds of the array, and i have no idea what causes it.

Answer (score 0):

If this fails:

```cs
int randIndex = rnd.Next(idArray.Length);
int random = idArray[randIndex];
```

Then either:

1. `idArray` is shared and is being swapped between the operations
2. the array is empty

We can rule out 1 because it is a local, not a field; therefore the problem is 2

(I'm not including the third option of `Random.Next` being broken, since that seems preposterously unlikely)

Comment: yeah but why is the array empty?
I tried your solution before but it still includes the same problem because it might still generate a number outside the bound of the array...

Comment: @yairco06 because zero rows we're returned from the query; I can't tell you why that was, you'd need to check the data: however, I will tell you that your code is ripe for SQL injection attacks. Never ever concatenate user input into a query. Use a parameter.

Comment: Ok i'll try, and about the sql injections it's fine because the only thing they can acess in this table is facts (the website is about "did you know?") so they can feel free to wander in that table (:

Comment: @yairco06 you do realize that freely available tools exist to extract *literally any table*, including better DB schema UI tools than many RDBMS have, from a SQL injection hole like this? More specifically, imagine searching for `foo' into #ignore; select * from sys.tables --` or similar. Saying "it is only the facts table" just means you don't yet understand how serious this is.

Comment: This was only for development purposes, I will parameterize the query at the end, but this is not what is currently bothering the program.

Comment: @yairco06 fair enough, but if I may suggest: `var ids = connection.Query<int>("SELECT Id FROM Facts WHERE category=@category", new { category }").AsList();`  with Dapper: does everything you want including parameterization, with much less code